# Spark streaming context hangs on stop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to write a spark streaming program where I want to gracefully shutdown my application in case my application receives a shutdown hook. I wrote the following snippet to accomplish this.

```
sys.ShutdownHookThread {
  println("Gracefully stopping MyStreamJob")
  ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
  println("Streaming stopped")
  sys.exit(0)
}
```

On calling this code only the first println is called. That is the second println Streaming Stopped is never seen. The last message I receive on the console is:

```
39790 [shutdownHook1] INFO org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/streaming,null}
39791 [shutdownHook1] INFO org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/streaming/batch,null}
39792 [shutdownHook1] INFO org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static/streaming,null}
15/10/19 19:59:43 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static/streaming,null}
```

I am using spark 1.4.1. I have to kill manually the job using `kill -9` for spark to end. Is this the intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have had the same experience with Spark 1.5.+.  Since `stop()` is still in docs and API I would think it has some value, but this might just be for internal use now... I simply `awaitTermination()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark added its own call to stop the StreamingContext.  [See this email thread.](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201509.mbox/%3CCA+AHuK=sARTxg9MSH0LQe0M1p7y8dMjf7sTk+N=GLSxh4m39jQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Your code would have worked prior to 1.4, now it will hang as you are experiencing.  You can simply remove your hook and the graceful shutdown should happen automatically.

You can now use the following configuration parameter to specify if the shutdown should be graceful:

```
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown
```

The SparkContext will be stopped after the graceful shutdown.  See:

["Do not stop SparkContext, let its own shutdown hook stop it"](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8ac71d62d976bbfd0159cac6816dd8fa580ae1cb/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala#L732)

Comment: I do not really get it. There used to be two options earlier gracefully and not so gracefully. How are those handled?

Comment: I get it. But I had made my program to handle different signals differently. I suppose that could would just have to go now. The earlier thing seemed more flexible to me though. Thanks for the help I will mark this as correct once I have verified it.

Comment: You can still handle your own signals, just don't call ssc.stop in your shutdown hook, Spark will take care of that one